# Retrieve alist from list of alists by value of specific key inside of it

Tags: list, alists

I'm probably missing something simple here but... I've got a list of alists parsed from JSON using `json-parse-string`. The list of alists is like the following (details omitted for brevity):

```
( ((id . 1) (url . "http://gnu.org") (description . "GNU Operating System"))
  ((id . 2) (url . "http://fsf.org") (description . "Free Software Foundation")) ... )
```

I'm trying to retrieve an alist from the list by the value associated to `id` in the alist.

E.g. `(function 2 list)` would return `((id . 2) (url . "http://fsf.org") (description . "Free Software Foundation"))`

Obviously I could `while` or `cl-loop` over the list to find this out, but what is more a Lispy way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the structure/sequence is very dependable then you might just do this:

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(cl-find 2 list :key #'cdar)
;; or
(car (cl-member 2 list :key #'cdar))
```

More robustly, you'd use one of the alist functions to obtain the correct value to test against.

```el
(cl-find 2 list :key (apply-partially #'alist-get 'id))
=> ((id . 2) (url . "http://fsf.org") (description . "Free Software Foundation"))

(cl-find "http://fsf.org" list
         :key (apply-partially #'alist-get 'url)
         :test #'string=)
=> ((id . 2) (url . "http://fsf.org") (description . "Free Software Foundation"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I find this answer the most elegant for my use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something like this:

```lisp
(setq toto '(((id . 1)
              (url . "http://gnu.org")
              (description . "GNU Operating System"))
             ((id . 2)
              (url . "http://fsf.org")
              (description . "Free Software Foundation"))))

(defun foo (val lst)
  "..."
  (let ((al  (cl-member val lst :key `(lambda (xx) (cdr (rassoc ',val xx))))))
    (car al)))

(foo 2 toto) ; => ((id . 2) (url . "http://fsf.org") (description . "Free Software Foundation"))
```

Or if you have `lexical-binding` turned on (i.e., non-`nil`), then just use this for `:key` - no need for the backquoting to insert the *value* of `val`, which would otherwise be a free variable:

```lisp
(lambda (xx) (cdr (rassoc val xx)))
```

Answer (score 2):

To find a item from a list, I will probably use `seq-find`

```
(seq-find
 (lambda (alist)
   (= (alist-get 'id alist) 1))
 '(((id . 1) (url . "http://gnu.org") (description . "GNU Operating System")) 
   ((id . 2) (url . "http://fsf.org") (description . "Free Software Foundation"))))
;; => ((id . 1) (url . "http://gnu.org") (description . "GNU Operating System"))
```